# rotate() applied to one of two equal DIVs does not align the background image perfectly

Tags: css

I have two DIVs

```
  <div class="nextButton" onclick="showSlides()"></div>
  <div class="prevButton" onclick="showSlides()"></div>
```

With this CSS

```
.nextButton {
  height:2em;
  width:2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  right: 2em;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: url(\'data:image/svg+xml;base64,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\');
  background-size:cover;
}

.prevButton {
  height:2em;
  width:2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  right: 4em;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  font-size: 18px;
  background: url(\'data:image/svg+xml;base64,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\');
  background-size:cover;
}
```

I was expecting them to line up perfectly, however, I can notice a slight displacement of few px.

See image below.

[image: Unaligned backgrounds]

I am looking for suggestions on how to get them to line up perfectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a scale transformation instead of rotate to have a perfect alignment.

```css
.nextButton {
  right: 2em;
}

.prevButton {
  right: 4em;
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}

.prevButton,
.nextButton {
  top: 0;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="nextButton" onclick="showSlides()"></div>
<div class="prevButton" onclick="showSlides()"></div>
```

You can clearly see the issue if you add border and you will notice a small gap at the bottom that you move to the top when you do a rotation.

```css
.nextButton {
  right: 2em;
}

.prevButton {
  right: 4em;
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}

.prevButton,
.nextButton {
  top: 0;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  border:1px solid green;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/PjxzdmcgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNHB4IiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNCAyNCIgd2lkdGg9IjI0cHgiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6c2tldGNoPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LmJvaGVtaWFuY29kaW5nLmNvbS9za2V0Y2gvbnMiIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIj48dGl0bGUvPjxkZXNjLz48ZGVmcy8+PGcgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgZmlsbC1ydWxlPSJldmVub2RkIiBpZD0ibWl1IiBzdHJva2U9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMSI+PGcgaWQ9IkFydGJvYXJkLTEiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKC00NjcuMDAwMDAwLCAtMTkxLjAwMDAwMCkiPjxnIGlkPSJzbGljZSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoMjE1LjAwMDAwMCwgMTE5LjAwMDAwMCkiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJNNDY4LDIwMi41IEM0NjgsMTk2LjE0ODcyNSA0NzMuMTQ4NzI1LDE5MSA0NzkuNSwxOTEgQzQ4NS44NTEyNzUsMTkxIDQ5MSwxOTYuMTQ4NzI1IDQ5MSwyMDIuNSBDNDkxLDIwOC44NTEyNzUgNDg1Ljg1MTI3NSwyMTQgNDc5LjUsMjE0IEM0NzMuMTQ4NzI1LDIxNCA0NjgsMjA4Ljg1MTI3NSA0NjgsMjAyLjUgWiBNNDgwLjY1Njg1NCwxOTYuODQzMTQ2IEw0ODIuMDcxMDY4LDE5OC4yNTczNTkgTDQ3Ny44Mjg0MjcsMjAyLjUgTDQ4Mi4wNzEwNjgsMjA2Ljc0MjY0MSBMNDgwLjY1Njg1NCwyMDguMTU2ODU0IEw0NzUsMjAyLjUgTDQ4MC42NTY4NTQsMTk2Ljg0MzE0NiBaIiBmaWxsPSIjMDAwMDAwIiBpZD0iY2lyY2xlLW5leHQtYXJyb3ctZGlzY2xvc3VyZS1nbHlwaCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoNDc5LjUwMDAwMCwgMjAyLjUwMDAwMCkgc2NhbGUoLTEsIDEpIHRyYW5zbGF0ZSgtNDc5LjUwMDAwMCwgLTIwMi41MDAwMDApICIvPjwvZz48L2c+PC9zdmc+');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="nextButton" onclick="showSlides()"></div>
<div class="prevButton" onclick="showSlides()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the circular part of your image is not centered, but is slightly below center.  Then, in the rotated version, it is slightly above center.

Add this to your css and then take careful measurements to see:

```
 div {border: 1px solid black;}
```

To fix that, you can change the encoding of the image.
But that might be difficult, so a less elegant way would be
to offset one or the other by changing the css.

For example, add "padding-top: 2px;" to the one that is too high.
Or, change the top value for one or both to other than 90%.
Or, put them a little bit apart horizontally and it will be less noticeable.

Comment: Whilst your answer can be the solution, theoretically, it is not best due to different sizes of viewports.

The accepted answer provides a perfect solution.